# How to place tick label above grid line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to place my tick labels just on top of the grid lines of my graph like it shows in the image below.

[image: Image of the graph I want to replicate]

I tried setting the direction to 'in' and the pad to -22 in  `tick_params` but I don't know how to move the labels slightly up to achieve what I want.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# My lists
dates = []
ratings = []

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

fig.set_facecolor('#2f3136')
ax.set_facecolor('#2f3136')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('grey')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('grey')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='grey')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='grey',direction='in',pad=-22)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.spines[['left','top']].set_visible(False)
ax.grid(axis='y')
fig.set_figwidth(10)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

plt.plot(dates, ratings)
```

And this is what I am getting

[image: The result of my code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `yticklabels` vertical and horizontal alignments (after  plotting) and it should look as expected.

```py
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), ha="right", va="bottom")
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='grey', direction='in', pad=-5)
```

Note that the `tick_params(pad)` value has been reduced since the text is already right aligned.

[image]